# Make PhpUnit test on xampp

Tags: php, xampp, phpunit

I am doing exercises on Exercism.io.
I have Xampp and I have to do a PHPunit test.

1. when I launch from cmd the command `phpunit.phar hello-world/hello-world_test.php` it asks me to open the phpunit.phar but it can't find the program
2. if I launch the file hello-world_test.php I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\hello-world\hello-world_test.php on line 6

I think I have some issue in where it catch the phpunit folder.

Can you help me?

Comment: I create the default exercism folder on c:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: I solved. I wrote phpunit.phar instead phpunit

Comment: You can post your solution as the answer and accept your own answer.